# Can the UA ranger's animal companion get a feat instead of an ASI?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, character-advancement, animal-companions, unearthed-arcana

I'm creating a revised beast master ranger and decided to get a pet panther. Since my pet gains ASIs whenever I do and we're using the optional feats rule, then can my pet get feats instead of ASIs too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No.

When asked if it was the intent to allow the beast companion to take feat instead of ASI, or if he personally would allow it, Jeremy Crawford answered:

> No on both counts.

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/776801113672515584

Answer (score 8):

**No, the animal companion isn't able to choose feats instead of an ability score improvement.**

The [Unearthed Arcana: Revised Ranger](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) states:

> Whenever **you** gain the *Ability Score Improvement class feature,* **your companion’s abilities also improve.** Your companion can increase one ability score of your choice by 2, or it can increase two ability scores    of your choice by 1. As normal, your companion can’t increase an    ability score above 20 using this feature unless its description specifies otherwise.

Your animal companion isn't gaining the *Ability Score Improvement class feature.* Their ability scores only increases alongside yours if **you** gain that feature<sup>1</sup>.

Since gaining a feat requires you to forgo taking that specific class feature (PHB, pg.165), not just giving up increasing your ability scores, your animal companion can't forgo what they don't have.

<sup>1</sup> Side note that if you *don't* take the ASI and instead choose to gain a feat, your animal companion's ability scores don't increase either.

Comment: Mike Mearls says if you take a feat, your animal still gains ability score increase.  That said, he was talking about their intent -- but only Crawford counts as official rulings.

Answer (score 1):

No as in the rules case, but I as a dm allow it. It matters what feat though. It makes sense for a panther to get the Alert feat, but not spell sniper, polarm master etc. It matters how much of a rule stickler your dm is.